# make[1]: *** No rule to make target `firmware/am335x-pm-firmware.bin', needed by `firmware/am335x-pm-firmware.bin.gen.o'. Stop

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, texas-instruments, 3g-network, android-kernel

I have a Ti Sitara AM335x Starter Kit and I want to use USB 3G-Modem on it.
I am following these documents:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-USB-3G-Modem-Integration & http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-JB-4.1.2-DevKit-4.0.1_DeveloperGuide#Build_Procedure

I didn't get sources via repo. I used Pre-packaged.
I can't build android linux **kernel** and get this error 
after this command

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- uImage
```

I have tried many things, including changing `pm-firmware.bin` to `pm-firmware.bin.gen.o`, Download ready kernel uImage and try to continue steps.

How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 8):

Surprised no one answered this.

From here:

http://elinux.org/Building_BBB_Kernel

Do this from above your kernel source folder:

```
wget http://arago-project.org/git/projects/?p=am33x-cm3.git\;a=blob_plain\;f=bin/am335x-pm-firmware.bin\;hb=HEAD -O kernel/firmware/am335x-pm-firmware.bin
```

-J

Comment: thanks, I've also had the same problem. But isn't it strange for a file to vanish? or not exist at all since the beginning, but suddenly becomes a need :/ I was compiling my kernel just fine.. anyway this helped :-)

Comment: ]> «But isn't it strange for a file to vanish? or not exist at all since the beginning»
.

Most likely .gitignore has a line preventing checking in such files. In my case it was am335x-pm-firmware.elf file.

Comment: With GCC 7.x "am335x-pm-firmware.bin" is being ignored, compiler stops with "no rule" message. I'm not sure what that firmware is for. The BBB works fine without it. Although I don't use PRU, for example.

Comment: am335x-pm-firmware.bin link is dead

Comment: You can get it from TI here: https://git.ti.com/cgit/processor-firmware/ti-amx3-cm3-pm-firmware/tree/bin

Answer (score 2):

The file was presumably in the kernel source tree when the kernel was built, and was
linked into the kernel image. That's why you don't see it in a distro filesystem.

The file is also not a part of official Linux firmwares, so you have to get it outside
as described above.

If you don't want to use it for some reason, you can disable this setting in  your .config file:
    CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE="am335x-pm-firmware.bin" ->
    CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE is not set